# Apple tv stopped working

Tags: battery, bluetooth, appletv, siri

I've recently bought apple tv for the bedroom and thought it was great.. at first.

I only really use it for netflix, but now my remote doesn't seem to be working. I thought maybe that the battery died so I left it on charge overnight to see if that helped (it didn't and it didn't show me any indication of being on charge either). I've used the same charger as I use on my iPhone so I don't think there's an issue with the power cable.. Have also tried re-pairing it using the menu and volume up button but still nothing.

I can only connect it through an ethernet cable if I take it downstairs and I don't have the remote app paired up on my phone (it won't let me connect it now)so all I have been able to do is stream things through air play which seems to defeat the purpose on buying this shiny new thing!

Extra info: I've got the newest box, I think it's 4th gen with the siri remote..

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: As long as you know that you're not holding the remote upside down (don't laugh, it's happened to many people) and you're sure that it's being charged, it's possible the remote is just bad. It's probably still under warranty so you can contact Apple to get it replaced.

Comment: Remote is definately not upside down (believe me I checked a million times haha!) and it doesn't show me any indication that it is charging, not sure if it's supposed to have a light on or anything :/

Comment: I don't believe there's a light on mine.  You might have a bad unit.  Bring it in to an Apple store or contact Apple Support via chat, they should be able to ship you a new unit.